# Boost::Asio async client - how to know the other side did TCP FIN?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am using a `boost::beast::tcp_stream` which wraps around a `boost::asio::basic_stream_socket` for an asynchronous client.

```
No. Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
...
117 0.261388597    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             HTTP/JSON 125    HTTP/1.1 200 OK , JavaScript Object Notation (application/json)
119 0.261398240    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     43794 → 8090 [ACK] Seq=47 Ack=257 Win=65408 Len=0 TSval=4119348562 TSecr=4119348562
121 0.261485938    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      66     8090 → 43794 [FIN, ACK] Seq=257 Ack=47 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=4119348562 TSecr=4119348562

122 0.273668580    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             HTTP     115    POST /api/clear HTTP/1.1 
123 0.273716187    127.0.0.1             127.0.0.1             TCP      54     8090 → 43794 [RST] Seq=258 Win=0 Len=0
```

The client sends a request to the server (not shown), and the server responds with HTTP 200 OK.

The client naturally returns an ACK.

The server is Python Flask, which has a habit of closing the connection even with HTTP 1.1, so it sends a FIN, ACK.

The client wishes to send the next HTTP request, and it definitely does a `boost::asio::io_context::poll()` to give it all the opportunity to receive this FIN from the server. The client then checks `boost::beast::tcp_stream::socket().is_open()`, and it falsely returns true, even though it has received the FIN from the server.

The only way I can see to check if the connection is closed is to attempt to write the next request, which the server complains about with an RST.

Surely there is a way to receive the FIN from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q.** The client wishes to send the next HTTP request, and it definitely does a boost::asio::io_context::poll() to give it all the opportunity to receive this FIN from the server.

You don't receive FIN. You *observe* it when attempting the next operation. There is a chance that [`async_wait` with `wait_type::read|wait_type::error`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_wait.html) can lead to earlier information. But the nature of stream sockets is that you will know on your next read/write. (Same for file stream EOF, really).

> **Q.** The client then checks boost::beast::tcp_stream::socket().is_open(), and it falsely returns true, even though it has received the FIN from the server.

You mean, it correctly returns `true` to reflect the socket is open. Even if the remote end shutdown the communications, the socket will remain open until **you** close it. That's important because you might depend on the error state, out-of-band communication or pending buffered data. It is **also** important to avoid race conditions where the same native handle gets re-used before you even notice the socket had been closed.

> **Q.** The only way I can see to check if the connection is closed is to attempt to write the next request, which the server complains about with an RST.

That's the way.

> **Q.** Surely there is a way to receive the FIN from the server?

- "Surely" you would be operating on the wrong OSI layer. So, yes, by all means, implement your own IP stack and design a better socket API on top that gives you this. Or, just live with the de-facto standards (POSIX, BSD, Winsock) that all behave the way you know.
- I think the most async clients commonly have an `async_read` pending at all times (as part of full-duplex communication). This will already tell you *immediately* when the server goes away. Or fails.
- *Note that there may be socket options (I'm not an expert, but I think `SO_KEEPALIVE` is close?) that will allow you to detect errors earlier. But (a) the behaviour may be non-portable (b) it may not be convenient in the framework of your choice (IOW it might not actually help unless you use custom - non-ASIO - interfaces). Just throwing it out there for your information.*

Comment: Oh I forget the "obvious": most application have an async_read pending at all times (for full-duplex comms). This will _surely_ notify you when the server goes away (although the server can still do an asymmetric shutdown). Adding the answer text too.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'll check the async_wait(). That looks like the most promising method. It seems suboptimal to run into a RST each time, but if that's the way. It is cumbersome to keep track of having to repeat the last request which was to a broken connection. Ah yes, I see the SO_KEEPALIVE platform-dependent way. I only do an async_read() when the corresponding write has completed, as the async client example does: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/async/http_client_async.cpp

Comment: Is there a way to know in the async_read() response what the corresponding request was? I haven't found a way yet, so simply reading continually doesn't let me know what the HTTP OK it just received was actually for. I currently keep track of the current request state separately, which must be the corresponding one for the one async_read().